# What do you call the compartment of a market stall?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the compartments and what do you call the whole sets of compartments?  Are there words for it? I am trying to fathom a guess, but I am thinking there are no more specific words for these.

Comment: I would just call them _shelves_ (with cupboards beneath).  I don't know of a special word for them in the context of a market stall.

Comment: Maybe slots? And the whole thing together, a display? exhibit? rack? ;)